# Button not showing up in my Jframe

Tags: java, swing

**Everything except the Button is showing up in the window. IS there something i am missing?**
This is the first time using Buttons and am not sure what's going wrong. It might be a formatting issue. 
Can somebody tell me if there is an issue with setLocation() and setSize()?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.TextField;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class HashString extends JPanel {


    public static void hashString() {
    }

    public void window() {
    JLabel label1 = new JLabel(
            "Enter Your Strings separated by a comma, below. ");
    label1.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    label1.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 12));
    label1.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.TOP);

    JTextField field = new JTextField(50);
    field.setVisible(true);
    field.setText("Enter Strings Here");
    field.setSize(300, 251);
    field.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
    field.setLocation(135, 60);

    Button btn = new Button("Enter These Values");
    btn.setLocation(240 ,420);
    btn.setSize(100, 100);
    btn.setVisible(true);
    btn.setFont(new Font("Times new roman",Font.BOLD,12));

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test1");
    frame.add(new HashString());
    frame.add(btn);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(field);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.add(label1);
    frame.setSize(600, 450);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}
```

}

Comment: It is, shoudlve added setVisible at the very end .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should change how you've structured the program. Instead of putting each position with a manual position inside the `JFrame`, you should simply use a layout manager, like `BorderLayout`, which can easily be implemented here.

Also, you should always address everything from the `EventQueue` and not any other threads. Furthermore, it is inadvisable to mix and match AWT components like `Button` and Swing components like `JButton`. While it is much better than it was before – like in Java 1.6 – but it still can turn up some issues.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class HashString {   // It seems that this isn't a JPanel. Rather, it is an application.

    JFrame frame;

    public void initialise() {

        frame = new JFrame("Test 1");   // You can create the frame of the application here and set title

        frame.setLocation(200, 200);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);

        JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();     // To allow a border to be set, I've declared a content panel inside the
                                                // frame.
        contentPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));    // This sets a border to make everything look nice
        contentPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5)); // This creates the BorderLayout, which manages the layout of
                                                        // the components easily
        frame.setContentPane(contentPanel);

        JLabel instructionsLabel = new JLabel("Enter Your Strings separated by a comma, below. ");
        instructionsLabel.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 12));
        contentPanel.add(instructionsLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);    // BorderLayout.NORTH tells the layout manager where
                                                                    // to put the component.

        JTextField txtField = new JTextField();
        txtField.setText("Enter Strings Here");
        contentPanel.add(txtField, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JButton btn = new JButton("Enter These Values");
        btn.setFont(new Font("Times new roman", Font.BOLD, 12));
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // Call whatever method that you want to call when this is relevant. Set textField and other variables
                // here. You can do things like 'txtField.setText( methodOperationOnString ( txtField.getText() ) )' or
                // something of the like.
            }
        });
        contentPanel.add(btn, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // This tells it to create the entire thing on the GUI thread
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                HashString b = new HashString();
                b.initialise();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: WOW! That is really helpful! I am used to doing everything manually

Comment: If your main method is in another class – change `public void initialise()` to `public HashString()`. Then it'll construct automatically when you invoke 'new HashString()`. You can also just remove the `main` if so.

Comment: Don't mix JavaFx and Swing. This is a Swing application. Don't try to initialise it from here. If you did so, (and you're in Eclipse), you need to remove the run configuration. Click the arrow next to the `Play button > Run Configurations > HashString` and click delete on that run config.

Comment: thank you x1000000

Comment: Oh yea, this is helpful. It's the Oracle tutorial on all the stock LayoutManagers in Java: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html